# No such field error within type with INCLUDE TYPE

Tags: abap

I've declared table gt_log_req this way because user asked for a new field zzname_create. Previously it used just standard alv type table, but there's no such field, so...

```
types: begin of ty_log_req,
 include type zmms_stock_rep_log_alv,
  ZZNAME_CREATE type resb-ZZNAME_CREATE,
  end of ty_log_req.

DATA: gt_log_req TYPE TABLE OF ty_log_req.
```

...and later

```
DELETE gt_log_req
         WHERE dtres_reasid <> '000'.
```

But this way i've experienced a 'no such field' error for dtres_reasid, but it presented in zmms_stock_rep_log_alv! Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have added a component named `INCLUDE` to your structure, so the field name would be `include-dtres_reasid`. I doubt that's what you intended, but you made a common entry-level mistake there: [`INCLUDE TYPE` / `INCLUDE STRUCTURE`](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_750/en/abapinclude_type.htm) are separate instructions that must be entered at the same level as the `TYPES` instruction. Thus, you need to end the `TYPES` statement, `INCLUDE` whatever you want and start with a new `TYPES` statement.

```
TYPES: BEGIN OF ty_log_req.
         INCLUDE TYPE zmms_stock_rep_log_alv.
TYPES:   zzname_Create TYPE resb-zzname_create, 
        END OF ty_log_req.
```

If you had used the pretty printer with case conversion enabled, you'd probably have spotted that earlier.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll have to enable pretty printer to evade this mistake next time.